# Убивается Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android

Добрый день! Пытаюсь сделать Alarm Manager, который каждую минуту будет выполнять определенные действия. Происходить это должно постоянно, не убиваться системной и при перезагрузке телефона запускаться. 
Однако при очистке недавних приложений и перезагрузке телефона аларм убивается.

Запускаю Alarm Manager

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        myIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,myIntent,0);

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),60*1000,pendingIntent);
    }
```

Receiver

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //...
    }
```

Receiver в Android manifest

```
   <receiver android:name=".service.AlarmNotificationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Что я делаю не так??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны 2 ресивера или один, но принимающий указание на то, что он должен делать. Ваша проблема в том, что вы задаёте очередь для `AlarmManager` только в активити. В итоге, после загрузки девайса у вас ваш ресивер вызовется... Но очередь для `Alarm Manager` не будет создана и более он вызван не будет.

Т.е. надо каждый раз при срабатывании ресивера на событие запуска девайса заново задавать очередь для `Alarm Manager`.

Попробуйте так:

1. Один ресивер для события запуска - в нём повторите код установки очереди для `Alarm Manager`. Т.е. и в нём, и в активити задавайте очередь.
2. Отдельный ресивер для приёма событий от `Alarm Manager` - в нём к-л логика

Comment: При перезагрузке телефона все получилось, а вот при очистке недавних приложений аларм не восстанавливается. ведь это можно же как-то сделать?Буду рад помощи!

Comment: При очистке недавних ничего пропадать не должно. Но только если не будет при этом force close приложения. Если он происходит, то сделать ничего нельзя. Попробуйте на другом девайса/по другому убирать приложение

Comment: Реально странно..на xiaomi просто как обычно очищаю недавно работающие приложения,и вот такая беда,на самсунге все нормально

Comment: @cotoSTR, на xiomi всё странно, да. У меня алармы, например, срабатывают после смахивания, но все сетевые запросы в них не проходят из-за SocetTimeoutException

Comment: а можно как-то отследить, что приложение очищается из недавних приложений?

Comment: @cotoSTR, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882533/3212712, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27498630/3212712